# How does the C# compiler deal with Nested classes using generic inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have seen the following construct many times in working code that I inherited and am trying to understand what this means:

```
public partial class Parent
{
    public class Child : Child<Parent>
    {
```

It seems that the class `Parent.Child` inherits from `Parent.Child<Parent>`

The confusing part, to me, is `: Child<Parent>`

How is the C# compiler dealing with this?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you're not understanding? Apart from the generic thing, this is just the same as a simple circular class reference (like class `A` has class `B` which has class `A`), and this isn't a problem at all.

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. You haven't shown a declaration of a `Child<T>` class, but assuming one exists, what's the problem? Why should the nested, non-generic `Child` class not be able to inherit the generic `Child<T>` class (wherever it's declared)?

Comment: Child<T> is a different class to Child - the compiler names it Child`1 behind the scenes. So it's just a coincidence that Child and Child<T> look similar. On top of that, as the non-generic Child is within the Parent class, so Child and Child<T> aren't in the same namespace

Answer (score 0):

C# compiler deals with it.

You can see those classes as 3 separate ones:

```
class Parent;
class Parent_Child<T>;
class Parent_Child : Parent_Child<Parent>;
```

I assume that kind of an explanation you are seeking for.